# Split a flat array into arrays of n elements

Tags: php, arrays, slice, chunks

There is an array containing K elements. What's the best way to get chunks of N < K items from this array?

Example input:

```
$x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // K = 10
```

Desired result, when N = 3;

```
$x1 = [1,2,3];
$x2 = [4,5,6];
$x3 = [7,8,9];
$x4 = [10];
```

Obviously, there is no need to store the result in variables. As long as it's possible to process it by foreach (or any other iteration logic), it should be fine.

The problem with `array_slice` is that it does not remove the N-slice from the beginning of the array. The problem with `array_shift` is that it does not support shifting more than 1 item at once. Is there anything more elegant than iterating over `array_shift`?

Comment: Have a look at `array_chunk` http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: `array_chunk` is the solution to the whole problem, but I think the function you were looking for is `array_splice`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is what you need.

```
<?php
$x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
print_r(array_chunk($x,3));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into array_chunk -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_chunk.asp

```
$x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
print_r(array_chunk($x,3,true));
```

or you could do it this way -

```
$x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   $chunks = array();
   while(count($x)){
    $chunks[] = array_splice($x, 0,3,array());
     $i++;
    }
```

Could someone tell me which method would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

array_chunk function is used to create sub arrays of equal size.
E.g.

```
$a=array_chunk($array,3);
```